# Multiplex array of photodiodes

Tags: amplifier, photodiode, analog-switch

I have a linear array of 10 photodiodes that I want to connect to a single transimpedance amplifier to produce signals.

I'm envisioning some sort of analog switching circuit (U2 in the diagram below) that selects which diode to connect to the amplifier based on a binary coded decimal [s3:s0] input.

Before I go too far down this rabbit hole I wanted to check if this is possible, and if so, what some pitfalls might be.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSel86.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>.

Comment: It depends upon your requirements; what sensitivity, noise bandwidth and other performance parameters do you need?

Comment: it is possible, but the question is too generic.

Comment: Can I suggest you add a little context, and, specifically what kind of photodiodes you plan to use.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can research, with the help of electronics.SE or on your own, what multiplexer ICs suit for your purpose, or, with some diligence, to design and manufacture the device. But your detector parameters are the primary factor of design choices.

There is a number of issues with a photodiode assembly made from individual photodiodes. Typically, people use photodiode arrays from manufacturers of optoelectronic devices. The manufacturers also supply driver circuit assemblies which provide not only multiplexing but also current-to-voltage conversion, timing, and buffering, and it is highly recommended to go this route in your practical design.